# Generating random color from seed?

Tags: algorithm

So basically if you look at Google Contacts. If user has a profile picture, then they show a profile picture. If not, they show a nice circle with first name letter in the middle.

Now the circles are of different colors. Although there seems to be a finite number of them, but they do spread out evenly (i don't really see 2 of the same colors side by side).

Well anyway, it seems that it is somehow derived from the user data, but probably not just hashed into HEX code.

So anyway, if I wanted to implement something like that... what approach should I take?

(I ask specifically about the generation of random (well not really random, as same entity always seems to get the same) colors, I have all the rest figured out)

Comment: Is it possible that there are just 26 different colors, one for each letter? Or can the same letter have different colors?

Comment: Nope, names starting with same letter have different collors. Maybe possibly... just a random color code gets assigned during registration.. and it is not derived at all.. I have no idea, that's why I am asking. Hopefully someone there that have implemented something like that, and can point me in right dirrection :)

Comment: In that case, I'd guess that they're using a [hue-saturation-brightness (HSB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) color model. The saturation and brightness are constants, and the hue is randomly chosen based on the name. There are formulas to convert HSB to RGB, which is what the hex code represents.

Comment: You could have a look at [Nextcloud's Contacts](https://github.com/nextcloud/contacts) implementation. Maybe [here](https://github.com/nextcloud/contacts/commit/8fc233da68b2e8884d0097bddfb2ca9d87177679#diff-601ed7eed0ca887f58f620f589b66180)?

Comment: It can be any sort of hashing. (e.g. the sum of bytes of first name + last name, mod x). Does it really matter?

Comment: @Bill Gates, yes it does, if you want beautiful colors.

Comment: @Peque niiiiiiiiiice. Thank you so much. Would you care to post is an answer, so I can mark it as accepted? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [Nextcloud's Contacts](https://github.com/nextcloud/contacts) source code.

See the [contactColor_filter.js history](https://github.com/nextcloud/contacts/commits/master/js/filters/contactColor_filter.js). And maybe in particular:

- [`8fc233da - js/filters/contactColor_filter.js`](https://github.com/nextcloud/contacts/commit/8fc233da68b2e8884d0097bddfb2ca9d87177679#diff-601ed7eed0ca887f58f620f589b66180).
- [`master - js/filters/contactColor_filter.js`](https://github.com/nextcloud/contacts/blob/master/js/filters/contactColor_filter.js)